# Show TextBox when ToogleSwitch changes state

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an uwp app, and I have a ToogleSwitch in my app, and I want show a TexBox when ToogleSwitch changes of state.
I know how to show Textbox, my question is how do I know when the Toogle Switch changes state (by the user).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Anniversary Update or later you can do this:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="MySwitch" />
<TextBlock Text="Hello world" Visibility="{x:Bind MySwitch.IsOn, Mode=OnwWay}" />
```

Cool huh?

> Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, the XAML framework provides a built in Boolean to Visibility converter. The converter maps true to the Visible enumeration value and false to Collapsed so you can bind a Visibility property to a Boolean without creating a converter. Note that this is not a feature of function binding, only property binding. To use the built in converter, your app's minimum target SDK version must be 14393 or later. You can't use it when your app targets earlier versions of Windows 10. For more info about target versions, see Version adaptive code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
 <TextBlock Name="MyText" Text="Lorem Ipsum..." />
 <ToggleSwitch Name="MyToggle" Toggled="MyToggle_Toggled"/>
```

Code Behind C#:

```
    private void MyToggle_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ToggleSwitch)
        {
            var toggle = (ToggleSwitch)sender;
            if (toggle.IsOn)
            {
                MyText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                MyText.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that when creating production software you would typically use data binding, but it sounds like you're just learning so I believe this is the answer you're looking for.